# Add number of moderator flags to mod analytics graphs

Tags: feature-request, flags, data-analysis

With the traffic increase on Ask Different, it feels as though we're getting more flags, but it's hard to know. Would it be possible to add an additional graph to the moderator analytics page for number of flags on each given day? This would be useful to see trends in how much moderator intervention is needed, and would allow community managers to identify sites in need of additional moderators. (Ask Different doesn't, but we might someday)