# Add 'Votes Per Post' to moderator analytics

Tags: feature-request, voting, analytics

Curious about voting on Ask Different, I wanted to see if the trend was up or down, as well as compare today to the private and public betas.

Trying to use Moderator Analytics to do this doesn't work very well because all that is displayed is total votes (it is broken down by up, down, and accept; and question vs answer in another section).

That information wasn't very useful to me because the volume of posts on Ask Different has changed a lot.
Comparing the Questions and Answers graph to the Voting graph doesn't really cut it since, without overlaying the two, it's hard to see anything other than a drastic change.

It would also be great if this could be broken down further into upvotes and downvotes per post, and possibly even votes per question vs votes per answer.

Comment: another 'add this to moderator analytics' post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109641/add-number-of-moderator-flags-to-mod-analytics-graphs

Answer (score 1):

I think [sustained drops in voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216297/1438) are a big concern.  Adding that to moderator analytics isn't a bad idea.

In the meantime, now that [beta sites are included in the data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188465/beta-sites-should-be-in-the-data-explorer), you can use this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/153363/votes-per-post-by-month#graph) to track monthly voting per post.

ben is uǝq backwards also [suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80312/why-are-votes-per-post-on-the-decrease-what-can-we-do-to-improve-this/216297?noredirect=1#comment700087_216297):

- [median votes using post date](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/160158/median-votes-per-post)
- [median votes using vote time](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/160160/median-votes-per-post)